# ddslick dropdown form post not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

post method does not work on the dropdown jquery ddslick

This is the form:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['usern'])){
    $value = $_POST['usern'];
if($value > 0)
{
echo "work";
} 
else
{
echo "not work";
}
}
?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://web-0a54fa71-eb5f-4cdc-bfbe-142bcd20757b.runnablecodesnippets.com/jquery.ddslick.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://web-0a54fa71-eb5f-4cdc-bfbe-142bcd20757b.runnablecodesnippets.com/script.js"></script>

        <form action='users.php?j=60' method='post'>

        <select id="demo-htmlselect-basic" form="post" name="usern">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option data-imagesrc="image.jpg" value="1"> Part 1</option>
        <option data-imagesrc="image.jpg" value="2"> Part 2</option>
        <option data-imagesrc="image.jpg" value="1"> Part 3</option>
        </select>

<input type='submit' value='Send'>

        </form>
```

This is the dropdown I used: http://code.runnable.com/UgC2a5sY1P8LAAAj/how-to-create-a-custom-drop-down-with-images-using-jquery-ui

Comment: can you post your entire code so we can see if you copied it all correctly? Edit your question and then put everything into the Javascript/HTML/css snippet tool.  See this image what to click  http://s32.postimg.org/x7oqo2bh1/post.png

Answer (score 0):

take me time to get what you want
u should use  values in the select list php cod  .i hope it help you man

```
<?php 

$values = $_POST['list'];
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'Submit')) {



echo $options[$value];
echo $values;
}
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://web-0a54fa71-eb5f-4cdc-bfbe-142bcd20757b.runnablecodesnippets.com/jquery.ddslick.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://web-0a54fa71-eb5f-4cdc-bfbe-142bcd20757b.runnablecodesnippets.com/script.js"></script>



  <form  method='post'> don't forget add the action page 

        <select id="demo-htmlselect-basic" name="list">
        <option value="0" >Select</option>
        <option value="1" > Part 1</option>
        <option  value="2"> Part 2</option>
        <option value="3"> Part 3</option>
        </select>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

        </form>
```